# Scheduling java program to update data using API

Tags: javascript, java, node.js

I have to update data in the `database` at a particular time daily. Data will be updated using `RestAPI`. I have to consume `API` either in `java` or `nodejs`.

Can you tell me how can I schedule the job in `java` or `nodejs`. Which one would be better for the above scenario?

The basic requirement is updating all the data in the database once in a day using `POST` `RestAPI`.

Any specific `example`?

Comment: I suggest you to use NodeJS with node-schedule (https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to handle both java jar and nodejs code, and that is the same project, and you want the consistent thing for scheduling both, you should you OS capabilities for that, I'll assume you use Linux or Unix like OS.

The tool is called CRON. Details here.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

You just need to create a shell script with launching the process.
And then configure it to run daily here is an example for 8 am.

```
0 8 * * *
```

For the cloud, there are services for that exists
Example of AWS is cloud watch.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/ScheduledEvents.html

Comment: Can I call java program from shell script?

Comment: Of course, you need to have an executable jar (jar with class and main method), if you're using spring boot app, there is a maven\gradle plugin exists, otherwise, you can just use maven shade plugin to specify class, create a jar with all its dependent libraries, after that you can just do java -jar /path/to/my/executable.jar

Comment: thank you @wtsiamruk . Can you please answer this as well?     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62538856/calling-multiple-api-in-sequence-with-token-in-java