# Calling multiple API in sequence with token in java

Tags: java, spring, rest, web-services, jax-rs

I have to call 5 `APIs` in sequence after generating the token. i am using below `API` to generate `token`.

```
POST https://idcs-xxxx.identity.c9dev2.oc9qadev.com/oauth2/v1/token
```

I will send `username` and `password` to get token in above API. Once token will be received I will have to use the `same token` to call below 5 `APIs` in sequence.
I will use `output` of one `API` and filter it and pick some values as an input to next `API`. all the `rest endpoint` will change based on the `input` value of previous `API` `response`.

```
GET https://idcs-xxxx.identity-t0.data.digitalassistant.oci.oc-test.com/api/v1/skills

GET https://idcs-oda-9417f93560b94eb8a2e2a4c9aac9a3ff-t0.data.digitalassistant.oci.oc-test.com/api/v1/skills/dynamicEntities

POST https://idcs-xxxx.identity-t0.data.digitalassistant.oci.oc-test.com/api/v1/bots/xxx/v2/yyy

PATCH https://idcs-xxxx.identity-t0.data.digitalassistant.oci.oc-test.com/api/v1/bots/xxx

PUT https://idcs-xxxx.identity-t0.data.digitalassistant.oci.oc-test.com/api/v1/bots/xxx/DONE
```

How can I `automate token generation` and the same `token` can be used in every `API call`. `token` will expire in every one hour. My only purpose is to automate above process somehow.
even smallest help would be highly appreciated. you can suggest even some part of solution if not all. I could not get much material from google.

Rather than coding I am interested in architecture.

Comment: Most ideal is to use spring security inbuild oauth client as mentioned correctly by @wtsiamruk in the comment. Having said that, if you have already written custom code for token generation and using it one of the API at least than that can be easily generalized for usage across all subsequent API. Let me know if that's what you are looking forward to, I can share few pointers using RestTemplate and interceptor in that case.

Comment: APIs are already created. I have to consume only. i can not use Spring because it is for Oracle product and they only use either JAX-RS or ADF. As a partner of oracle we have to use their product

Answer (score 1):

Spring Security will help you here.

https://spring.io/blog/2018/03/06/using-spring-security-5-to-integrate-with-oauth-2-secured-services-such-as-facebook-and-github

Comment: I can not use spring. I have to consume API either in JAX-RS or in ADF framework of java

Comment: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CXF20DOC/JAX-RS+OAuth2